# Javascript: a webform that doesnt refresh the page when the user submits the form

Tags: javascript, ajax, webforms

I want to have an email newsletter subscription form on my website that doesnt refresh the page when the user enters their email address and submit, but rather leaves a "Thank you" text in the email field. Does anyone know how to this using Jquery and AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Well, `this is a request that changes a lot based on your scenario`. But a basic example would be:

```
<form class="ajax" action="/newsletter/subscribe" method=POST>
    <input type=text name=email/>
    <input type=submit/>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).on("submit", "form.ajax", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var form = $(this);
          $.ajax({
               url: form.attr("action"),
               type: form.attr("method"),
               data: form.serialize(),
               success: function(){
                // handle success
               },
               error: function(){
                // handle error
               }
           }
</script>
```

Other solutions may vary a lot, but i tried to keep it simple. Thanks.